# Why does AES_cbc_encrypt() not return encrypted ciphertext in plaintext during decryption?

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, aes

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt a string buffer in AES 128 CBC mode. I went with CBC because it lets me encrypt entire arrays at once. Encryption seems to work fine as the messages seemed to be ciphered, but decryption does not. Instead of returning plaintext, the resulting output becomes unintelligible when the cipher-text is about to be decrypted.

This is the code I'm using to test encryption and decryption

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>

#define AES_KEY_SIZE 128
#define AES_BLOCK_SIZE 16

void encryptMessage(const char *message, size_t messageLen, const unsigned char *key, const unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *ciphertext) {
    AES_KEY aesKey;
    AES_set_encrypt_key(key, AES_KEY_SIZE, &aesKey);

    AES_cbc_encrypt((unsigned char *)message, (unsigned char*)ciphertext, messageLen, &aesKey, (unsigned char *)iv, AES_ENCRYPT);
}

void decryptMessage(const unsigned char *ciphertext, size_t ciphertextLen, const unsigned char *key, const unsigned char *iv, char *decryptedMessage) {
    AES_KEY aesKey;
    AES_set_decrypt_key(key, AES_KEY_SIZE, &aesKey);

    AES_cbc_encrypt(ciphertext, (unsigned char *)decryptedMessage, ciphertextLen, &aesKey, (unsigned char *)iv, AES_DECRYPT);    
    //size_t paddingLen = decryptedMessage[ciphertextLen - 1];
    //decryptedMessage[ciphertextLen - paddingLen] = '\0';
}

int main() {
    const unsigned char key[AES_KEY_SIZE] = "mysecretkey1234";
    const unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE] = "abcdefghijklmnop";

    char message[1024];
    unsigned char ciphertext[1024];
    char decryptedMessage[1024];

    printf("Enter a message: ");
    fgets(message, sizeof(message), stdin);
    message[strcspn(message, "\n")] = '\0';

    size_t messageLen = strlen(message);

    encryptMessage(message, messageLen, key, iv, ciphertext);

    decryptMessage(ciphertext, messageLen, key, iv, decryptedMessage);

    printf("Original Message: %s\n", message);
    printf("Encrypted Message: ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < messageLen; ++i) {
        printf("%02x", ciphertext[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Decrypted Message: %s\n", decryptedMessage);

    return 0;
}
```

And the resulting output

```
Enter a message: asdadfadfadfa
Original Message: asdadfadfadfa
Encrypted Message: 70bbb018fc29b4a5255938ea7a
Decrypted Message: p???)??*R7?v?%?
```

aes.h doesn't seem to provide a separate function to decrypt the cipher-text as we are instructed to just use the AES_cbc_encrypt function then pass AES_DECRYPT as a parameter to decrypt. This is what the documentation has to say. Let's hope I'm right.

> AES_cbc_encrypt encrypts (or decrypts, if enc == AES_DECRYPT) len bytes from in to out. The length must be a multiple of the block size. This function may be called in-place with in equal to out, but otherwise the buffers may not partially overlap. A partial overlap may overwrite input data before it is read.

> OPENSSL_EXPORT void AES_cbc_encrypt(const uint8_t *in, uint8_t *out, size_t len, const AES_KEY *key, uint8_t *ivec, const int enc);

I tried fixing the problem by adding a null terminator to the decrypted message which you can see in the last two lines of the decryptMessage() function but that didn't seem to work. I'm honestly lost here. I also thought that converting the resulting plaintext from hex to ASCII might work, but from the looks of it, the plaintext wasn't in hex and sure enough, it didn't work. What am I missing here? I've been searching for other examples online with regards to AES implementation in C but could not find anything that's relevant to the scope of the project I'm working on. Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're not checking any return values - you have no idea how many bytes of ciphertext your encryption call returned, or even if it worked at all.  AES/CBC encryption will pad the ciphertext.  You don't seem to be accounting for that, but it's hard to read your code and be sure as the long lines make it almost impossible to see how parameters are passed.

Comment: One fix: encrypt the whole _string_, including it _null character_: `size_t messageLen = strlen(message) + 1;`,   Then once decrypt issue is figured out, `printf("Decrypted Message: %s\n", decryptedMessage);` won't be UB, as it is now.

Comment: Try it on [AES Online Encryption](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption).  Unable to get the same encoded hex string.  Try with `"mysecretkey12345"`, what encrypted string do you get?

Comment: Yeah there's something wrong with my program's encryption. They result in different ciphers. Let me see what's going on and I'll get back to you. Thanks @chux-ReinstateMonica